# iOS 5 and app store

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

Not sure if this has been asked yet, but it is a very important question for our app development company: we are debating the installation of iOS 5 on our devices, but need these devices to develop and test apps for the app store. Would installing iOS 5 disrupt that process? That is, would we still be able to upload and test apps on Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you mean XCode 4.2. Xcode 4.0.2 will run iOS 4.3.  XCode 4.2 will run iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 7):

I would keep iOS 4 on some devices and install iOS 5 on the others. You are allowed to test your apps on iOS 5 but that doesn't necessarily mean that the apps will work on iOS 4.

Comment: The problem is I only have one stable development device. Rrght now we release apps for earlier versions by changing some key values, do you know if that would be possible with iOS 5?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't installed iOS 5 myself yet.

Comment: +1 I think this is the the best advice.  If you say you have only one device, my advice is, "get another".  You can get a used iPod Touch on craigslist for like $100.  If you absolutely can't do that, I wouldn't recommend iOS5 yet - it's early still.

Answer (score 2):

Just installed iOS 5 and everything is working without a hitch. No issues so far uploading anything to apple (just make sure you set your project to use an earlier version of the SDK).

Hope this helps!